# how to pass date array as xml to store procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Bcz when u parse that string into date that will not parse properly.
for that u have to send date string as per sql server date format

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SprSelectScheduleForReAutoAllocate]  --'<AADates><AADate AADateValue="2011-04-27 00:00:00.000" /><AADate AADateValue="2011-04-28 00:00:00.000" /></AADates>'
(
   @Datexml xml     
)
AS
BEGIN
                  EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @xmlDoc output ,@DateXml 

                                SELECT  AADateValue
        FROM OPENXML(@xmlDoc,'AADates/AADate',1) 
        WITH 
        (
        AADateValue Datetime    
        )
        xmlDocuments

                EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @xmlDoc  
End
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server reads date times values according to the ISO 8601 standard in the following two formats:

```
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.mmm]
YYYYMMDDThh:mm:ss[.mmm]
```

Format you input like this and SQL Server will never throw an error due to incompatible culture or language. This is the culture/language agnostic way to pass the value if you cannot pass it as an actualy `datetime` value.

Comment: No, that's the point, the date format doesn't change. This is an format agnostic literal value. It will ALWAYS succeed in being converted to a valid datetime value.

Comment: SET DATEFORMAT ydm; using this code you can change date format

Comment: You need to make sure that the formatted dates in the @Datexml don't use the standard or built format typical to XML because that is not well understood by SQL Server, make sure you stick to the ISO 8601 format if you have to pass dates as strings in or out of SQL Server.